# How to convert string Map to JSON string in java?

Tags: json, jackson, gson

I have fact an issue related to convert string map to string json with below example

````
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String stringRequest = "{A=12, B=23}";
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(stringRequest));
    }
}
```

 OUTPUT: "{A\u003d12, B\u003d23}"

Please you help me how can I map this to json string.
````

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what actually is your problem but the main thing in your example is that you are serializing a String object to JSON. That is why you get such an output, it is not a presentation of a `Map` but a `String`.

However with that string you can easily create a `Map` which you can then serialize. Not saying there is any point on that unless you want to do some cleaning or so but anyway:

```
// Check first which kind of types are keys & values
// keys are always Strings and here it seems that values can be Integers
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Integer>>(){}.getType();

// Create the actual map from that string
Map<String, Integer> map = getGson().fromJson(stringRequest, type);

// Serialize the map to the console (added pretty printing here)
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map));
```

and you can see:

> { "A": 12, "B": 23 }